# How to monitor and log session of mt apache web server

Tags: linux, apache, logging, webserver, redhat

I have redhat 5 server with apache web server . I hosted files on my server to allow my clients to download it and measure download rate.

I want to know details of my clients session including (client ip address, time of accessing my web page, download rate, session duration)

I dont know if httpd log file will contain needed information or not and I need your advise with any free tool to install to support in needed action.

Answer (score 0):

after searching i found the way to monitor all transactions done on your Apache server by **Custom Log Formats**, more over you can modify which information to keep in access log (Client IP address, download file name, time stamp, uploaded data size, downloaded data size, duration , ...)

/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

- modify LogFormat line to be like in below

LogFormat "%h %t %I %O %D %f %b %l %u \"%r\" %>s \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined

- Uncomment below line

CustomLog logs/access_log combined

%h : Remote hostname

%t : Time the request was received, in the format [18/Sep/2011:19:18:28 -0400]

check below link for full details

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html